# Regex to allow only one word followed by a url

Tags: regex

I am currently doing something like this

```
std::string reg ="^/house/room/section/.*"
```

This allows the user to pass any word after section which my program picks up and uses.However I only want the user to be able to put in one word not a sentence after section. How can i modify (.*) to anything that does not have a space in it.
For instance

```
/house/room/section/A1343         ALLOWED
/house/room/section/A1343 A1002   NOT ALLOWED because a space was found inside the follow up word
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a character class that disallows spaces, like so:

```
[^ ]*
```

or you could specify non-whitespace characters:

```
\S*
```

Comment: Thanks , what if I wanted to add the char "/" to it as well so a word that does not have a space or the character "/" in it

Comment: In that case just add "/" to the character class: `[^ /]*` This will match any number of characters that are not a space or a slash.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

`"^\b[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\b$"`

It will only allow letters, numbers, and the underscore sign `_`, since these are the characters that when put together will be interpreted as "one word" by your machine.